# Using HTML date format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, date

I am hoping you can help.

I am trying to use a date format field in HTMl, which will then use this date in JavaScript. Once it has read the date, it will work out whether it is within 3 months or not.

At the moment, it is returning saying invalid date entered. How do I get JavaScript to read the date when using a HTML date format?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<title>ICT5</title>

<script>
function checkdate() {
var UserDate = document.getElementById("date").value;

var parts = UserDate.split("/");
var dt = new Date(parseInt(parts[2], 10),
              parseInt(parts[1], 10),
              parseInt(parts[0], 10));

               window.alert("userdate is" +dt);

var timestamp = new Date().getTime() + (90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
window.alert("" +timestamp);  


if (timestamp > dt){
alert("Selected time is less than 3 months from now");
} else {
alert("Selected time is more than 3 months from now");
}


}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<h1>ICT 5 a</h1>

<h1> Working out the difference between today and your selected date </h1>
<p> Please enter a date </p>
<input id="date" type="date">
<button type="button" onclick="checkdate()">Submit</button>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Which throws the error? dt or timestamp?

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/hkb0utqu/1/) what you want?